# Upgrading MariaDB 10.1.32 version to 10.3.7

Tags: mariadb, upgrade

Is it possible to upgrade from 10.1.x to 10.3.x directly in **one step? or I have to upgrade first to 10.2. x  then to 10.3.x.**

Please it is so important question regarding upgrading our production MariaDB servers and I couldn't find any answer or notes regarding upgrade from 10.1 series to 10.3 series.

**So i have to do it as follow: 
10.1.32 --> 10.2.16 
10.2.16 --> 10.3.7 
or 
once 10.1.32 --> 10.3.7**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, for any upgrade for a critical production environment:

- The best approach is to use or create a test environment that is as close as possible to your production environment and test the upgrade there.
- Make backups and prepare a rollback so you are ready to undo your changes

For MariaDB specifically: to quote from other related questions on their support pages:

> The main concern with skipping versions is that, while upgrading one major version is usually well-tested, skipping versions is not, so you
>   may bump into an incompatibility

Even if you find anecdotal indications that it worked for others, a database engine like MariaDB has possible complexities with different storage engines and the like that might make it more tricky in certain setups than in others.

Comment: Thanks, actually I thought that since we are using InnoDB as storage engine and we don't have any deprecated options in my.cnf file so direct upgrade can be possible. But as you said it is best to test and step by step upgrade is safer.

Answer (score 3):

1 : Shutdown or Quit your XAMPP server from Xampp control panel.
2 : Download the **ZIP version** of [MariaDB](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/10.2.10/)
3 : Rename the xampp/mysql folder to mysql_old.
4 : **Unzip** or **Extract** the contents of the MariaDB ZIP file into your XAMPP 
    folder.
5 : Rename the MariaDB folder, called something like mariadb-5.5.37-win32, to 
    mysql.
6 : Rename xampp/mysql/data to data_old.
7 : Copy the xampp/mysql_old/data folder to xampp/mysql/.
8 : Copy the xampp/mysql_old/backup folder to xampp/mysql/.
9 : Copy the xampp/mysql_old/scripts folder to xampp/mysql/.
10: Copy mysql_uninstallservice.bat and mysql_installservice.bat from 
xampp/mysql_old/ into xampp/mysql/.
11 : Copy xampp/mysql_old/bin/my.ini into xampp/mysql/bin.
12 : Edit xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini using a text editor like Notepad. Find **skip-federated** and add a # in front (to the left) of it to comment out the line if it exists. Save and exit the editor.
13 : Start-up XAMPP.
 **Note** If you can't get mysql to start from Xampp control panel.
    Add this 'skip-grant-tables' statement anywhere in xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini 
    file
14 : Run xampp/mysql/bin/mysql_upgrade.exe.
15 : Shutdown and restart MariaDB (MySQL).
           If still **mysql is not started then follow below Note steps(!Important)**

**Note**  :**mysql error log file:** c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: unknown variable 'innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2M' like please remove or commented this statement in my.ini file in this path **xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini file**.

Help from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027926/update-xampp-from-maria-db-10-1-to-10-2/47490206#47490206).