# How do I upgrade MariaDB to v10.3 on XAMPP

Tags: xampp, mariadb

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but I'm finding conflicting information. I need to upgrade to the latest version of XAMPP, and I've found the directions to do that. But it uses MariaDB v10.1, and I need MariaDB v10.3.

If someone has already given an answer to how to upgrade XAMPP to MariaDB v10.3, I'd appreciate it if you'd point me in the right direction. So far, all I've found is directions for v10.2.

Specific questions:

- Do I need to upgrade to MariaDB 10.2 before upgrading to MariaDB
  10.3, or can I do this all in one step?
- Do I need to export the existing databases (or just my databases) and
  import them after I've upgraded, or can I just copy the 
  C:\xampp\mysql\data, C:\xampp\mysql\scripts and C:\xampp\mysql\share 
  directories? My existing databases are WordPress databases, if that matters.

Thanks,
Vicki

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update xampp from maria db 10.1 to 10.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027926/update-xampp-from-maria-db-10-1-to-10-2)