# Error in generated column (MySQL) in Laravel by storedAs()

Tags: php, laravel, migration, mariadb

here is my migration script

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            .
            .
            .
            $table->decimal('coupon_discount')->default(0);
            $table->decimal('delivery_charge')->default(0);
            $table->decimal('sub_total')->default(0);
            $table->decimal('total')->storedAs('(sub_total + delivery_charge) - coupon_discount');
            $table->decimal('paid')->default(0);
            $table->decimal('due')->storedAs('total - paid');
            $table->longText('note')->nullable();
            .
            .
            .
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

i have to create [generated-columns](http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/) for total and due columns.

but while i tried to run the migration file its showing exception

Exception:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'stored, `paid` decimal(8, 2 ) not null
>   default '0', `due` decimal(8, 2) as (total' at line 1 (SQL:

```
create table orders (
    id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, 
    user_id int unsigned null, 
    area_id int unsigned not null, 
    location_id int unsigned not null, 
    delivery_add ress longtext not null, 
    delivery_address_id int unsigned null, 
    mobile varchar(191) not null, 
    email varchar(191) null, 
    coupon_id int unsigned null, 
    coupon_discount decimal(8, 2) not null default '0', 
    delivery_charge decimal(8, 2) not null default '0 ', 
    sub_total decimal(8, 2) not null default '0', 
    total decimal(8, 
    2) as ((sub_total + delivery_charge) - coupon_discount) stored, 
    paid decimal(8, 2) not null default '0', 
    due decimal(8, 
    2) as (total - paid) stored, 
    note longtext null, 
    order_type tin yint not null, 
    delivery_type tinyint not null, 
    status smallint not null default '0', 
    payment_method tinyint not null, 
    payment_channel smallint null, 
    payment_status tinyint not null default '0', 
    created_at timestamp null, 
    updated_at timestamp null
) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
)
```

**Note:** i have 
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.35-MariaDB, for Win32

what i missed ?

Comment: Your error message says you are using MariaDB, not MySQL.  What version of MariaDB are you using, as generated columns may not always have been supported?

Comment: Can you execute the corresponding create table statement directly against MariaDB?  If you can't, then at least you'll know that it is not a PHP problem.

Comment: It is working in mysql..

Comment: i have mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.35-MariaDB, for Win32 (AMD64) @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: which mysql version you using @SachinAghera

Comment: @EmtiazZahid 4.5.4.

Comment: The `STORED` keyword requires MariaDB 10.2.1+: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/generated-columns/

Comment: look like i should upgrade my MariaDB. thanks @JonasStaudenmeir

Answer (score 0):

**[Solved]**

It was my MariaDB version problem, not PHP

Upgraded MariaDB 10.1 to 10.3. now its working fine.

followed the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027926/update-xampp-from-maria-db-10-1-to-10-2)

*Thanks Jonas, Sachin, Tim*

Comment: `STORED` was not available until MariaDB 10.2.