# How to stop XAMPP's MySQL Service after updating MariaDB

Tags: mysql, service, xampp, taskkill

I've updated my MariaDB to version 10.3.14 using this steps ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027926/update-xampp-from-maria-db-10-1-to-10-2))

It has been successfully installed, but when I tried to stop the MySQL Service from XAMPP Control Panel, it won't stop.
The status always shows like this:

> [mysql] Attempting to stop MySQL app...

Like the picture below:
[image: img]

How can I stop that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can kill the process operating on port 3306.

Type in CMD (Command Prompt) if you have windows:

```
netstat -ano | findstr :<yourPortNumber>
```

put your port number in the diamond brackets.

then put the process ID in diamond brackets,

```
taskkill /PID <typeyourPIDhere> /F
```

Answer (score 4):

I also had this issue so for anyone looking for an answer to fix the panel rather than using taskkill from cmd here is why this is happening:

The XAMPP Control panel you have installed is 32bit, while upgrading your MariaDB by following [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027926/update-xampp-from-maria-db-10-1-to-10-2?noredirect=1&lq=1) you downloaded the 64bit MariaDb version. That is why the XAMPP panel will not stop the MySQL process.

Download the 32bit version of MariaDB and re-do the installation process and it should be all sorted.

Comment: Because I don't need 64bit version, I use 32bit and fix XAMPP panel

Answer (score 1):

Open up cmd.exe(PORT= your port number)

Step 1

`netstat -ano | findstr :<PORT>`

Step 2

`taskkill /PID <PID> /F`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.